# Using GetClass with Delphi runtime packages

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2.2 Toyko to develop a runtime package, but calling `GetClass()` in my app does not find my Form class in my package.

In the package, I have the following code (just a form):

```
procedure CreateForm;
begin
  // Create instance of class TfmFormInPKG in Application
  fmFormInPKG := TfmFormInPKG.Create(Application);
  fmFormInPKG.Show;
end;

procedure DestroyForm;
begin
  // Validate the instance
  if Assigned(fmFormInPKG) then
  begin
    // Destroy the instance if assigned
    fmFormInPKG.Destroy;
  end;
end;

initialization
  RegisterClass(TfmFormInPKG);
  // Call procedure CreateForm when the package is loaded
  CreateForm;

finalization
  // Call procedure DestroyForm when the package is unloaded
  DestroyForm;
```

In the calling app, I have this code:

```
procedure TfmTestVCLDPK.btnCreatePKGClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FormInPKG: TForm;
  FormClass: TPersistentClass;
  HandlePack: HModule;
  theCaption: Variant;
begin
  // try to load the package
  HandlePack := LoadPackage ('pkgTheVCLPKGXE10.bpl');
  if HandlePack > 0 then
  begin
    FormClass := TPersistentClass(GetClass('TfmFormInPKG'));
    if Assigned (FormClass) then
    begin
      with TComponentClass(FormClass).Create (Application) as TCustomForm do
      begin
        ShowModal;
        Free;
      end;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage ('Form class not found');
    UnloadPackage (HandlePack);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage ('Package not found');
end;
```

While it appears that I do get a handle to the package, `GetClass()` always returns `nil`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the calling App is also compiled using Packages?

Comment: Or at least, are the App and Package both compiled to share the same external `rtl` package?

Comment: On a side note, `if HandlePack > 0 then` should be `if HandlePack <> 0 then` instead, and `FormClass` should be declared as `TCustomFormClass` so you can get rid of all the unnecessary type-casting when constructing the Form object: `var FormClass: TCustomFormClass; ... FormClass := TCustomClass(GetClass('TfmFormInPKG')); ... with FormClass.Create (Application) do ...`

Comment: Also, `DestroyForm()` should set `fmFormInPKG` to `nil`, in case `DestroyForm()` is called multiple times. You can simplify `DestroyForm()` to just `procedure DestroyForm; begin FreeAndNil(fmFormInPKG); end;` and let `FreeAndNil()` do all of the work of validating and nil'ing for you.

Comment: How do I ensure that rtl is included in the app - it does not seem to be visible in the project.

Comment: Problem solved - must tick the link with runtime packages in the project options - foolish oversight